# Why does my variable only activate in certain situations

Tags: java, variables

in my running class I have a variable called `requestClosing` that when it is true, it opens a new window and closes the old.  When I click on it, It says that requestClosing is true, but it does nothing.  After 5 seconds, I set it to true and it works as intended.  Why does it do this and how can I fix it?  Thanks in advance

```
boolean requestClosing = false;

public void running() {
        Game game = new Game();

        if(currentTime+1000 < System.currentTimeMillis()) { //Calculates One second
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();// Resets the calculations
            secondsPassed += 1; // How many seconds have passed since the last reset or start of game.
        }

        if(requestClosing) { //<-- This does not work
            try {
                windowTwo();
                loadingScreen();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(secondsPassed > 5 && openAllowed) {
            requestClosing = true;
            openAllowed = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might also want to show us where and how you initialize your variables...especially `requestClosing`

Comment: I don't really use requestClosing anywhere else.

Comment: You should try to print out the value of `requestClosing` before the if-statement that will initiate the new window to have an overview about the variable state...